# Changing of the size of integer array when passing by value

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just curious what is the reason for the following error: I'm trying to determine the size of an integer array.

When I find the size of array in main function, this code returns correctly:

```
 int program[12] = { 1007, 1008, 2007, 3008, 2109, 1109, 4300, 0, 0, 0, -99999 };
 cout<<sizeof(program)/sizeof(program[0])<<"\n";
```

But if I pass program to a function by value, it always return 2:

```
void Sipmletron::load(int program[])
{
    int length=sizeof(program)/sizeof(program[0])
    std::cout<<length<<"\n";
    memory= new int[length];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass arrays by value. The argument is passed as a pointer to the first element of the array, so you are in effect calculating `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int)`.

Comment: +1: although i agree with your answer, isn't the size of a pointer and an int the same? So my thought was that length would be 1 instead of 2?

Comment: it should be mentionned the value 2 means pointers are twice the size of integers on the OP's platform, probably 64 bits (8) for int *, and 32 bits (4) for int.

Comment: @Calpis: We can probably guess that the compiler used targets a 64-bit environment. But if I 'm not mistaken, theoretically it's also possible for `int` to be just 16 bits.

Comment: That's correct, the OS is 64 bits. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed in C++ (and in C), it looses it's size (it's passed as the address of the first element, no matter whether it is `int *` or `int []`).

You can use `std::array` if you are using C++11, which has a `size()` member function, similar to vector. In almost all other aspects, it is the same as a standard C style array.

Otherwise, you have to pass the size along with the array - or use some marker to indicate the end (looks like you already have that with `-99999`).

Comment: Hence the word "almost" in there...

Comment: Oh, so it is. Sorry about that then :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two special-case language rules at play here, both inherited directly from C.

1. An expression of array type, in most contexts, is implicitly converted to ("decays to") a pointer to the array's first element. The exceptions in C are when the expression is the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`, or when it's a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array (sub)object. C++ has more exceptions, but none that apply here.
2. A parameter defined as `some_type foo[]` is "adjusted" to `some_type *foo`, so your parameter `program` is really a pointer, not an array. (This adjustment occurs *only* for parameter declarations.)

These rules (unfortunately IMHO) work together to make it *appear* that you're passing an array object by value, and accessing an array inside your function, but in fact it's all pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with templated member functions if you really wanted to:

```
    template <size_t N>
    void Sipmletron::load(int (&program)[N])
    {
      size_t length = N;
      std::cout << length << "\n";
      memory = new int[length];
    }
```

In addition, and even without seeing the rest of your code, I'm feel sure it would be worth your while looking at using a `std::vector` instead of doing your own memory management using `new`, with a more idiomatic `load(...)` that used iterators.